# I need help fixing my first program's bugs

Tags: python

I'm trying to write my first program that just gets an input from the user, selects a random number from 1 - 10, and checks to see if the user's number and computer's number matched.

Here's the code I tried:

```
def Num_Guess():
  print("Hello! Welcome to the \"Guessing Game!\"")

  import time
  time.sleep(2)

  print("Input a number from 1-10 and see if the computer has the same number!")

  time.sleep(2)

  User_Guess = input("Pick a number between 1 and 10: ")

  def int_check(User_Guess):
    if User_Guess.isnumeric() == True:
        User_Guess = int(User_Guess)

        def range_check(User_Guess):
          if User_Guess == range(1,10):
            print("Great! Your guess was", User_Guess, end='')
            print("!")
            return User_Guess

          else:
            print("Sorry, please pick a number between 1 and 10.")

            time.sleep(2)

            #Deletes the variable so that the global version does not override the local one.
            del User_Guess
            User_Guess = input("Pick a number between 1 and 10: ")
            int_check(User_Guess)
        
        range_check(User_Guess)

    else:
      print("Sorry, please pick a NUMBER between 1 and 10.")

      time.sleep(2)

      del User_Guess
      User_Guess = input("Pick a number between 1 and 10: ")
      int_check(User_Guess)
    
  int_check(User_Guess)

  time.sleep(2)

  #Picks a random number between 1 and 10.
  import random
  n = random.randint(1, 10)
  print("The computer picked" , n , end='')
  print("!")

  time.sleep(2)

  if User_Guess == n:
    print("The numbers match! You and the computer both picked" , User_Guess, end='')
    print("!")
  elif not User_Guess == n:
    print("The numbers did not match. You picked" , User_Guess , "and the computer picked" , n , end='')
    print(".")

  time.sleep(2)

  def Reset_Quit():
    rq = input("Restart or quit? (r/q): ")
    if rq == "r":
      print("\n")
      Num_Guess()
    if rq == "q":
      print("Quiting...")

      time.sleep(2)

      quit()
    else:
      print("Sorry, please say either \"r\" or \"q\".")

      time.sleep(2)

      Reset_Quit()
  Reset_Quit()

Num_Guess()
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish is:**

1. Checking if the user's input is numeric or not. If yes, it will move on to the next step which is converting the string to an integer. If it is not, then it will simply make the user re-enter their input.
2. The next step will be checking if the input is within the range of 1 - 10. If it is, it will move on to comparing the user's input and the computer's to see if they match. If it is not, it will make the user redo their input and have it go through the numeral checking process again.
3. The final step is making the reset/quit promptly to not allow numbers or any other character that could cause the program to crash other than "r"/"R" or "q"/"Q".

Comment: What is wrong with your code

Comment: Hi @Mr. Unknownymous, congrats on getting your first question posted. Can you edit the question title to accurately describe the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: In order to confirm a numeric input from user, the following conditional test will work.  `if User_Guess != "" and User_Guess.upper() == User_Guess.lower():` This will work with integers and floats.

Comment: Having said that, your code needs some work. For example you only need to `import time` once.

Comment: @Derek His or her minimal reproduced code doesn't have many import statements. How can you say that he has  many `import time` statements. But yeah, you should import at global level

Comment: @PCM the import statement is inside a function so every time that function is called it will `import time` again and again many times through out a game.

Comment: Oh yeah, what you say is right. Sorry, my bad

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code, but I'd like to point out only one: don't use [`quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#quit). To cite the documentation: of `quit` and `exit`: "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Comment: Oh ok, well, is there another way to end the program? -Matthias

Answer (score 1):

I understood what the problem is.

In your range_check function, you are trying to match the user input with a range (which is a generator object) using `==`. So instead use `in` keyword -

```
def range_check(User_Guess):
          if User_Guess in range(1,11): # Here was the error
            print("Great! Your guess was", User_Guess, end='')
            ...
```

Edit:
The program asks user to enter a number from 1-10, but program logic only accepts numbers 1-9. Rest of your code also uses the logic for including numbers 1-9 only. So correct the user input prompt to "number between 0-10" or "number from 1-9".
If you want to include 10 also:
use `range(1, 11)` and `randint(1, 11)`

Comment: ```range``` is a generator